# Пишет в консоле, что файл CSV does not exist

Tags: pandas, numpy, csv, файловая-система

Помогите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю в чем проблема. Все пакеты установлены, файлы скачены и открыты в Питоне. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где находится скрипт и `csv` файл? В директории `C:\Users\Anna`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указали относительный путь к файлу, поэтому `Python` ищет файл `airline-passengers.csv` в той директории, из которой Вы запускаете скрипт, то есть в `C:\Users\Anna`. Его там нет, поэтому возникает ошибка.

Предполагаю, что он у Вас находится в `C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\Временные ряды`.

Вы можете:

- Указать абсолютный путь:

  ```py
  read_csv(r'C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\Временные ряды\airline-passengers.csv')
  ```
- Перейти в директорию с файлом (в консоли):

  ```py
  cd "Desktop\Временные ряды"
  ```
- Указать путь относительно текущего каталога:

  ```py
  read_csv(r'Desktop\airline-passengers.csv')
  ```
- Изменить текущий каталог средствами `Python`:

  ```py
  import os


  os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Anna\Desktop\Временные ряды')
  ```

  или

  ```py
  os.chdir(r'Desktop\Временные ряды')
  ```